# What is the best way to test concordance between two sources?

Tags: agreement-statistics

I have gathered RNAseq data from two different papers. They are measuring the same genes in supposedly the same population of cells and I would like a way to quantify how well they agree.

No need to know anything about the field. The data are simply counts for ~ 20,000 genes. Each paper did triplicates. So for gene *n*, I have a set of 3 counts from paper 1 and a set of 3 counts from paper 2.

It looks like what I want to do is similar to the inter-rater reliability, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) is suggesting a bunch of different statistics to measure it, and I am not sure where to start.

What would be the best way to proceed?

Comment: Can you give more details about the variables and the research design?

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset?